# I walked over to the payphone to try to call you

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Does this sentence make sense?

I'm just confused with all the 'to's

Comment: Yes, it makes sense.

Comment: *I went **to** the payphone **to** try **to** call you **to** see if you wanted **to** go **to** the movie **tonight.*** (Not sure if that last one might be a stretch ***too*** far! :)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence makes perfect sense. The first to has different meaning then the other two to's. Also it is a different part of speech as it turns out the first is a preposition:

> I walked over to the payphone

The to here is used in sense one as given in the oxford dictionaries

> 1: Expressing motion in the direction of (a particular location)
>
> Example:
> My visit to Africa

The second and third are what's apparently called infinitive markers

> To try to call you

These are according to the same dictionary

> 1 Used with the base form of a verb to indicate that the verb is in the infinitive, in particular.
>
> 1.1 Expressing purpose or intention:
>
> I set out to buy food

Answer (score -1):

Being a native-English speaker, I don't see any grammatically problem in your statement. However, I feel it's a little bit odd. And if you ask me to rewrite it in my words then I will rewrite something like:

> I walked over to the payphone and tried to call you.

Thanks.

Comment: While this sentence is perfectly correct I don't think it has the same meaning. In particular it cannot be used as an answer to the question "Why did you walk over to the payphone?"

Comment: @DRF Hi! I am new to this website, so please don't take me as an outsider here.-:) And I just wrote which I would have said instead of the questioner. And please don't try to push me out. Just joking........

Comment: @DRF I walked to it because I wanted to use it. You asked me: "Why did you walk over to the payphone?" I went there because I wanted to use the payphone to call someone. What's wrong here?

Comment: I find it slightly jarring too. With 'went' I'd not have the same feeling. There's a suggestion that walking (rather than hopping) to the phone was part of the necessary procedure; your version shows sequentiality, which does not cause the same frisson.